# ExpressJs Serve multiple static folders not working

Tags: node.js, express

I want to structure my public folder like this:

```
 - public
     -  frontend
     -  backend
     -  assets   # to serve common css, and js static files for backend/frontend
```

if the request is prefixed by /admin then I want to serve backend folder, else then the frontend folder
this is what I've tried

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    if (req.url.match('^\/admin')) {
        express.static(__dirname + '/public/admin')(req, res, next);
    } else {
        express.static(__dirname + '/public/frontend')(req, res, next);
    }
});

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public/assets'));

app.get('*', function(req, res, next) {
    if (req.url.match('^\/admin')) {
        res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/admin/app/views/index.html');
    } else {
        res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/frontend/app/views/index.html');
    }
});
```

but I can't get the static files from the assets folder, it keeps giving me index.html instead.
what is the right approach to make it works ? thx alot

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, I think something like this would be more the way to go.

```
app.use('/admin', express.static('public/backend'));
app.use('/', express.static('public/frontend'));
```

Comment: omg, I dont even know why did i do it like that, thanks a lot dude, it works

Answer (score 0):

You can do this way

```
app.get('/*', function(req, res) {
  if(req.path.indexOf('/admin/')!==-1) 
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'public/admin', 'index.html'));
  }else {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'public/frontend', 'index.html'));
  }

});
```

You can similarly add other urls as well.